# Basic linux shell scripting: getting NTP at linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ntp

I want to write a shell script for getting NTP(Network Time Protocol) info for debian server.

How can I write, I don't know ?

Comment: what are you trying to do: print out the time given by a remote server, or set the current machine's time with NTP?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing your own? There are lots of existing tools to do this. `openntp` is one example. Look in aptitude.

Is there a reason you can't use the existing tools?

Comment: Not course work, I send this info to campfire message.It's for integration.Only I need NTP time info for server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at ntpdate manpage for details on how to use this command.